# Determine for which α ∈ R the series is absolutely convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine for which α ∈ R the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\big(e^{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} + \pi n -1\big)}{\ln(\arctan\frac{1}{n})}n^\alpha$$

is:
a) aboslutely convergent,
b) convergent,
c) divergent.

I've tried an approach where I considered the nominator and the denominator separately using direct comparison test for both and:

- Taylor's theorem to approximate  $e^{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$ as $e^x = x + 1 + o(x):$

$e^{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = {\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} + 1 + o(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) $

- The fact that $\arctan\frac{1}{n} = \frac{π}{2} -\arctan{n} $

Neither of these helped me solve this problem. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

and since $\sin(x+n\pi) = (-1)^n\sin x$, we have an alternating series as well. That's it for the numerator, now looking closely at the denominator we have that

$$\log\left(\arctan\frac{1}{n}\right) \sim \log\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = - \log n$$

meaning that (calling the above series $\sum a_n$) :

$$|a_n| \sim \frac{n^{\alpha - \frac{1}{2}}}{2\log n}$$

For $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ this will always diverge. At the very least for $\alpha < -\frac{1}{2}$ the series will converge absolutely. I will leave it to you to prove that statement, and figure out where else the series will absolutely or conditionally converge.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what happened to sin in the numerator when you approximated |an|, could you explain?

Comment: @szymon $\sin x \approx x$ for small $x$